# WriteableBitmap shapes rendering

Tags: silverlight, drawing

I am trying to render some Shape objects(Line, Rectangle) in Silverlight and I am using WriteableBitmap.Render(myShape, transform). The problem is that Render function seems to be missing antialiasing. Am I missing something or this is not possible using WriteableBitmap?

```
    private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        bmp = new WriteableBitmap(800, 600);
        testImage.Source = bmp;
        line = new Line() { X1 = 10, X2 = 500, Y1 = 10, Y2 = 300 };
        line.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        line.StrokeStartLineCap = PenLineCap.Round;
        line.StrokeEndLineCap = PenLineCap.Round;
        line.StrokeLineJoin = PenLineJoin.Round;
        line.StrokeThickness = 1;
        CompositionTarget.Rendering += new EventHandler(CompositionTarget_Rendering);
    }

    private void CompositionTarget_Rendering(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bmp.Render(line, line.GeometryTransform);
        bmp.Invalidate();
    }
```

Comment: Can you just paste your snippet of code what you have done until now. Anmother thing can you please elaborate what you want to achieve ?

Comment: I added the code that does the rendering.

Comment: ok as i see there is no wrong in code u r doing , whats the problem here. Using WriteableBitmap you can easily render lines or any shapes . The code snippet you edited renders the line and it works fine .